# camelCase to css-case (reverse of attrs.$normalize)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`attrs.$normalize('foo-bar')` will produce `"fooBar"`. Is there an Angular function that will take `"fooBar"` and produce `"foo-bar"`?

Or do I need to write one, if I need this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^([a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])/` to match lower case letters followed by uppercase letter , `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` .

```js
var str = "fooBar";
var res = str.replace(/^([a-z]+)(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1-").toLowerCase();

console.log(res)
```

---

Or,  following @AtesGoral , using `.split()` with `RegExp` `/(?=[A-Z])/` , `.join()`

```
'fooBarBaz'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Or: `'fooBarBaz'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase()`

Comment: I prefer your code with replace. I believe it's more performatic than split/join

Answer (score 2):

Here's an angular representation using `$filter`:

**Filter**

```
app.filter('decamelize', function() {
  return function(input) {
    // Credit to Ates Goral
    return input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('-').toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

**Usage**

```
Expression: {{camelCase | decamelize}}
JavaScript: $filter('decamelize')('decamelizeMePlz')
```

**Output**

```
helloWorld --> hello-world
fooBar --> foo-bar
decamelizeMePlz - decamelize-me-plz
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RO2yrf06e5vZklGAVkQ7